# Aligning social media sharing buttons to look nice together

Tags: html, css, web, styling

I just put back the social sharing buttons to my home page and they look really terrible together :)

You can take a look at it here on the bottom of the page: http://www.comehike.com

How do people usually make them fit so natural together? Mine look so disordered and unprofessional.  Is there anything that can be done with styling?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a screenshot.  Otherwise, it just looks like you're trying to drive traffic to your site, a SO no-no.

Comment: @Wonko screen shot isn't good because people will need to view source anyway, and maybe look via Firebug.

Comment: Have you even tried to code something? What is natural for you might not be for me, what is unprofessional for you might not be for me... Please try coding something first, and then come back with clear concise question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code you'll likely have to add individual classes to each one, as they are all in different elements. There are a few approaches, absolute positioning, display:inline but I'd recommend floats

add a ul element and each of your 'share buttons' as an li child element of that ul

```
<ul class='shareLinks'>
<li>facebook here</li>
<li>twitter here</li>
</ul>
```

then your css can look something like this

```
ul.shareLinks { overflow: auto; }
ul.shareLinks li { list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
```

you can obviously edit the css how ever you wish, the main point is the float: left the overflow: auto; on the ul is a fix for the floated elements not having a real height.